# where's the code from 'build' folder on asp.net c# (mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, uploadify

I have to fix a bug on a website that is using asp.net and i don't know much about it (asp.net c# mvc)...

the problem is in a plugin named uploadify, and it calls for the script to upload files:

```
'script': '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Build/UploadImages")%>/<%= ViewData["build_id"] %>',
```

in the browser show like this:

```
'script': '/prod/cms/Build/UploadImages/680ad442-8e9c-459c-b253-e9c389c1622b',
```

the problem is that the folder 'Build' doens't exist, i think it's created by asp.net....

I can't find the code that uploads the file... I searched everywhere with the words 'SaveAs', 'SaveFileAs', 'Upload', 'Uploadify' in all files, and i still haven't found it yet...

the problem that uploadify gives is 'HTTP Error' after it show 100% of upload, I searched on google but no luck... i think if i found the script that uploads the file, maybe i can fix it

here's the all script of my file:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Framework.Models.Image>>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Photo
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>
        Photo</h2>
    <p>
        <label>
            Tipo:</label>
        <%= Html.DropDownList("type", (SelectList)ViewData["types"], new { onchange = "changeScript(this.value)" })%>
    </p>
    <div id="dvUpload">
        <input id="upload" name="upload" type="file" />
        <a href="#" onclick="Upload('<%= ViewData["build_id"] %>')">Fazer Upload</a> | <a
            href="javascript:$('#upload').uploadifyClearQueue();">Limpar Uploads</a>
    </div>

   <%-- <% using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImages", "build", new { id = ViewData["build_id"], type = "c1956908-64f5-4195-ba73-4d7710d560d7" }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
       {%>
            <input id="File1" name="upload" type="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
    <%} %>--%>
    <br />
    <br />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
            </th>
            <th>
                Type
            </th>
            <th>
                Imagem
            </th>
            <th>
                Legenda
            </th>
        </tr>
        <% foreach (var item in Model)
           { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= Html.ActionLink("Apagar", "deleteimage", new { id = item.Properties.id, build_id = item.Properties.build_id }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Confirma esta ação?')" })%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.Type)%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="<%= Cms.Helpers.Settings.CMS_ADDRESS + item.Properties.url_address %>" width="150" height="100" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.TextBox(item.Properties.id.ToString(), item.Properties.description) %>
                <input type="button" value="Ok" onclick="saveLegend('<%= item.Properties.id.ToString() %>')" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
    <p>
        <%= Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
    </p>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderContent" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/JS/swfobject.js") %>"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/JS/jQuery/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.js") %>"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var html = "";

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            html = jQuery("#dvUpload").html();

            jQuery("#upload").uploadify({
                'uploader': '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/Flash/uploadfy.swf") %>',
                'script': '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Build/UploadImages")%>/<%= ViewData["build_id"] %>',
                'cancelImg': '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/Images/cancel.png") %>',
                'folder': '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/Images") %>',
                'multi': true,
                'simUploadLimit': 10,
                'fileDesc': 'Apenas Imagens são permitidas',
                'fileExt': '*.gif;*.jpg;*.png',
                'onError'      : function(errorType) {
                    //alert('The error was ' + errorType.toSource());
                    alert(JSON.stringify(errorType, null, 4));
                },
                'onComplete': function() {
                    alert("foi tudo");
                }
            });

            AddNullValueSelectObject('type');

        });

        function Upload(build_id) {
            jQuery('#upload').uploadifyUpload();
        }

        function changeScript(val)
        {
            jQuery("#dvUpload").empty();
            jQuery("#dvUpload").html(html);

            var culture = jQuery('#culture').val();

            jQuery("#upload").uploadify({
                'uploader': '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/Flash/uploadfy.swf") %>',
                'script': '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Build/UploadImages")%>/<%= ViewData["build_id"] %>?type=' + val,
                'cancelImg': '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/Images/cancel.png") %>',
                'folder': '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/Images") %>',
                'multi': true,
                'simUploadLimit': 10,
                'fileDesc': 'Apenas Imagens são permitidas',
                'fileExt': '*.gif;*.jpg;*.png',
                'onError'      : function(errorType) {
                    //alert('The error was: ' + errorType.toSource());
                    alert(JSON.stringify(errorType, null, 4));
                },
                'onComplete': function() {
                    alert("foi tudo");
                }
            });
        }

        function saveLegend(id)
        {
            var text = jQuery('#' + id).val();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/build/UpdatePhotoLegend")%>/' + id,
                data: 'legend=' + text,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('Alterado com sucesso!');
                }
            });
        }
        function AddNullValueSelectObject(object_id) {
            jQuery('#' + object_id).append("<option value='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'>--- SELECIONE ---</option>");
            jQuery("#" + object_id + " option[value='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000']").attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
    </script>

</asp:Content>
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: It's possible that the script is embedded as a resource. Try using ILSpy to confirm this. In that case you will need to access the source code. Also, it maybe that the script was minified/obfuscated and that's why you can't find anything.

Comment: thanks, I found it using ILSpy and decompiling the dll..

Answer (score 0):

Normally I wouldn't answer unless I was fairly sure of my answer, however, since noone else is responding...

I have no experience with uploadify but it looks like you are using an old version of uploadify and  the api has changed quite a bit so it's hard for me to say for sure.  I think the 'script' parameter is actually referring to the server side "script" that would normally handle the saving of the uploaded file (the 'uploader' parameter in the current version http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/uploader/).

Do you have a BuildController class with an UploadImages action (method)?  If so, that is probably one of the causes of your error (something erroring while saving to disk).  If you do have a BuildController, I wonder if that call to resolve url is correct?  The resolved path looks off to me (normally you would not resolve a route based url in mvc as resolve url isn't route aware).

If you don't have a BuildController and I'm totally off let me know and I'll remove this answer.  It's somewhat a shot in the dark.  But it is plausible.

EDIT:  Just in case you have no experience in MVC at all, the code from the "Build folder" should be located in your mvc web app under a folder called Controllers inside a class called BuildController inside a Method called UploadImages.

Answer (score 0):

**Promoted my comment to an answer**

It's possible that the script is embedded as a resource. Try using ILSpy to confirm this. In that case you will need to access the source code. Also, it maybe that the script was minified/obfuscated and that's why you can't find anything.